# Difference between square and inscribed circle as a function of angle

Tags: geometry

I'm working on a simple geometric problem, namely to find the one-dimensional difference $d$ between a square and a circle that touches the square at four points. I thought I had the problem solved, but my solution only works in the domain from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians. I included my work in a picture at the bottom of the question.

To be clear, my question is this: Is there a better way to solve this problem? If so, what is it? Keep in mind that I am in high school calculus, so I may not know/understand many higher-level concepts, if they apply here.

[image: My work]

Comment: @AndrewLi That's where the maximum value would occur, and it makes sense. My problem with the equation I derived is that it gives incorrect results past $\frac{\pi}{4}$, due to the asymptotic behavior of the secant function. I was wondering if there was a way to solve it without a limited domain.

Comment: But why would you expect your equation to be applicable to angles other $\pi\over 4$ if it's based on the assumption of a circle inscribed in a square.

Comment: @AndrewLi I plan to use this equation as a way to project a sphere from a cube, so I figured I would need to use more angles. Am I wrong in that assumption? I do suppose I could do a modulus operation to find an equivalent answer within the domain.

Comment: Seems like an XY-problem. It would've been beneficial to just've stated your intent in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct.

Note that the circle that you have is an inscribed not an circumscribed circle.

Also since the angle $\theta $ in your picture is $\pi /4$ your solution simplifies.

$$ D=R(\sec (\theta) -1) = R(\sqrt 2 -1)$$

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on my terms, I'm not too big on geometry. So there is no solution with a larger range?

Comment: It is not a better way but it is a better answer. It has been mentioned that the angle is always $\pi/4$ so the secant  function has no role in the solution.

Comment: I do not think there is a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: I drew the angle at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as an arbitrary one to visualize the problem. I apologize if it was unclear, and thank you for your solution.

Comment: @jetscooters As long as you work with circle and square the angle is fixed at $\pi /4$

Comment: Thank you for your attention.